# In C++, how to access attributes from a subclass of an object that was once created as subclass, but then copied to superclass?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

Consider the code below (**note: after rightful criticism I reworded the question**):

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class DataSuper {
    public:
        DataSuper() {}
};

class DataSub : public DataSuper {
    public:
        int a;
        DataSub() {}
};

class Super {
    public:
        DataSuper data;
        Super() {}
};    

class Sub : public Super {
    public:
        Sub(DataSub i) {
            data = i;
        }
        
        void test() {
           // I would like to print the value of data.a
        }
};    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DataSub dataSub;
    Super* s = new Sub(dataSub);
    s->test();
    delete(s);
    return 0;
}
```

`Super` has an instance of `DataSuper` called `data`. `Sub`, a subclass of `Super`, has the same object `data`, but it is an instance of `DataSub`, which inherits from `DataSuper`.

In essence, I would like to access `data.a` from class `Sub`. I know I can do it with having `data` as a pointer and then use `dynamic_cast`, but not sure if this is good practice.

Is there a way I can avoid it WITHOUT having `data` as a pointer?

Comment: Your use of `static_cast` is misguided. `Super::data` _is not_ a `DataSub` instance. It is a `DataSuper` instance. Telling the compiler to treat it as though it's a `DataSub`, which takes up more space, is asking for trouble. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: Additionally, the lack of a virtual destructor results in undefined behavior.

Comment: There's other issues with this code than potential memory leaks. https://godbolt.org/z/cqqv3WK7v

Comment: Segmentation fault and memory leaks are orthogonal concepts. You seem to be conflating them. Seg fault comes from accessing a resource you do not have and a memory leak results from not putting away resources that you do have. A seg fault can result in a memory leak if the program crashes before it can put resources away, but you've got bigger problems than the leak if the program is crashing.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the object is an instance of DataSuper without static_cast?

Comment: *Is there a way to ensure that the object is an instance of DataSuper without static_cast?*  Yes.  And, if this isn't just some obtuse programming sudoku, that's what you should do.  (But it will slice.)

Comment: Ok, it is not, it is just that I would like to do this without using pointers, and I am completely unaware on how to do it. Having only data in the superclass, but having the constructor by reference, would it work?

Comment: RIght now, as designed, `Super::data` is _always_ an instance of `DataSuper` and _never_ an instance of `DataSub`, no matter what casts you do. If you want the actual type of `Super::data` to vary, then you need a layer of indirection like using a `std::unique_ptr<DataSuper>` or similar.

Comment: The shown code expects objects in C++ to work like they do in Java or C#. C++ is not Java or C#, and objects don't work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: Please study C++ from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of guessing how it should work. You will save yourself a lot of misery if you start from a solid foundation.

Comment: I am going then to rephrase this question differently.

Comment: *I would like to do this without using pointers* It is okay to use pointers as **private member variables**, because the code will strictly control how they are used, so you can *programmatically* ensure they are being used as expected.

Comment: No problem as keeping them private - the public example is just a way to make the sample code simpler.

Comment: Related: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) `Sub`'s constructor is *slicing* its `i` parameter when assigning it to the `Super::data` member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Super::data` isn't a `DataSub`, but you're treating it like it is one.

Remember, in C++ a variable of object type *is* the object.  It is not a reference or a pointer or anything like that unless you declare it to be.  `Super::data` is a `DataSuper` and it can never be anything else.  Forcibly pointing a `DataSub&` at it like you have here will not end well.

If you want to share a `DataSub` between your `Super` and `Sub` classes you'll need to use a pointer.  For example:

```
class Super
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<DataSuper> data;
    Super(std::unique_ptr<DataSuper> data) : data{std::move(data)} {}
};

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
    using Super::Super;

private:
    // Use this if you need to treat data as a DataSub
    DataSub& dataSub()
    {
        return static_cast<DataSub&>(*data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Super> s = std::make_unique<Sub>(std::make_unique<DataSub>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efe0df5cf09c4e95)

---

If you want to avoid the extra allocation for `data` that this requires, you could reverse the ownership direction.  That is, have `Sub` pass a non-owning pointer to a `DataSub` to `Super`'s constructor and have `Sub` own the object:

```
class Super
{
public:
    Super(DataSuper* data) : data{data} {}
    
private:
    DataSuper* data;
};

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
    Sub() : Super{&data} {}

private:
    DataSub data;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Super> s = std::make_unique<Sub>();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/947892cca257957b)

Note that this approach is slightly less safe than the first approach since `Sub::data` isn't yet initialized when `Sub`'s `Super` subobject gets initialized.  If you try to use the object pointed to by `Super::data` in `Super`'s constructor you'll quickly wander into the land of undefined behavior.  The same goes for `Super`'s destructor.  `Sub::data` gets destroyed before the body of `Super::~Super` gets executed, so attempting to access the object pointed to by `data` from `Super`'s destructor body will also result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful. I changed my code to use your first suggestion, unique_ptr and make_unique and it worked like a charm.